# O evento submit não funciona quando tento registrar

Tags: jquery, formulário

Pessoal estou com um problema no meu jquery, o código abaixo mostra o momento
que registro o evento submit ao clicar no botao

```
$("#quero-me-identificar").click(function () {
   if($(this).is(":checked")){
     $("#painel-dados-usuario").show();

     $("#login-card").show();
     abrirLogin();
  }
});


function abrirLogin() {

$("#loginForm").submit(function (event) {
    console.log("sdf");
    event.preventDefault();
});


}
```

Meu código html

```
<form id="loginForm" method="post" action="">
   <button id="entrar" class="botao-login" style="float: left;margin-right: 15px">
    Entrar
   </button>
</form>
```

O problema que ocorre é que a ação não entra no evento *submit*, sendo que eu já fiz um `$("#loginForm").length` e ele consegue identificar que existe um formulário

Já tentei de outras formas e não consegui alguém pode me ajudar

Comment: Para fazer o evento submit ocorrer via javascript você precisa dar um trigger nele $("#loginForm").trigger('submit');

Comment: Na verdade não precisa, um `$("#loginForm").submit();` bastaria, mas ele está dando um `event.preventDefault();` então ele vai precisar fazer um  `$("#loginForm").unbind('submit').submit();`

Comment: Pois é eu fiz dessa forma e funcionou quando clico no botao sendo do tipo button mas quando clico no botao do tipo submit para dar o submit ele não cai no evento que eu registrei entendeu.

Comment: Vc quer remover o `event.preventDefault();`?

Comment: Não eu queria que continuasse, eu queria que entrasse no evento submit que eu registrei e parasse depois com o event.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0):

Como você está utilizando `event.preventDefault();` no seu `$("#loginForm")`

você vai precisar usar uma o `.unbind()` para fzer o submit no local que você quer

```
$("#loginForm").unbind('submit').submit();
```